# How can I get results from a given array with following conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and doing an online test to improve my skills. I came across to this question:

1. Add 1 point for each even number in the array
2. Add 3 points for each odd number in the array
3. Add 5 points every time the number 5 appears in the array

So if I am given this array as an example:
([1,2,3,4,5])
the output should be 13

This is what I have got so far:

```
export function find_total( my_numbers ) {
  
  for(let i = 0; i < my_numbers.length; i++){
  if(my_numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
    total = total + 1
  }
  if(my_numbers[i] % 2 === 1) {
    total = total + 3
  }
  if(my_numbers[i] === 5) {
    total = total + 5
  }
  return total
  }
  console.log(total)
}
```

But it is giving me errors. I get the logic in English but couldn't put it in JS.
What would be the right syntax here?

Comment: _“the output should be 13”_ — Why? You have two even numbers, three odd numbers, and one five. That’s 1 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 5 = 16.

Comment: The error I get is _“Uncaught ReferenceError: `total` is not defined”_. [_“In strict mode, assignment to an undeclared identifier is a **ReferenceError**.”_](/a/1471738/4642212). _“The [`export`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statement is used when creating JavaScript modules […] Exported modules are in strict mode […]”_. Put `let total = 0;` inside the function, at the top. `return` exits a function. You unconditionally exit the function _inside_ the loop. Obviously, it should be after the loop.

Comment: And of course, if you get _“Uncaught SyntaxError: `export` declarations may only appear at top level of a module”_, then see [ES2015 import doesn't work (even at top-level) in Firefox](/q/37624819/4642212) and read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statements.

```js
function find_total( my_numbers ) {
  let total = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < my_numbers.length; i++){
    if(my_numbers[i] === 5) {
      total = total + 5
    }
    else if(my_numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
      total = total + 1
    }
    else if(my_numbers[i] % 2 === 1) {
      total = total + 3
    }
  }
  
  return total;
}

console.log(find_total([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

This code should print the correct result of 13.
You were not getting an answer of 13 because 5 is odd so has 3 point and 5 point exclusive to 5. The key is not to treat 5 as having point of odd number but having it's own point irrespective of either it is odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

There are following issues in your code:

1. `total` in the function `find_total` is never initialized
2. `return` statement is misplaced inside the `for` loop, it must be outside, signifying return value of the function `find_total`
3. Better to `console.log` the value of the function, instead of logging it inside. eg. `console.log(find_total(...))`

Fixing these, you will indeed get the return value as `16` for input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as pointed out in the comments.

```js
function find_total(my_numbers) {

  let total = 0 // Initialize total with a value of 0

  for (let i = 0; i < my_numbers.length; i++) {
    if (my_numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
      total = total + 1
    }
    if (my_numbers[i] % 2 === 1) {
      total = total + 3
    }
    if (my_numbers[i] === 5) {
      total = total + 5
    }
  }

  return total // return outside the loop
}

console.log(find_total([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) // console.log outside
```

Comment: If you properly fix your logic as per my answer you'll get an answer of 13.

Comment: Is 5 not an odd number?

Comment: It is. But as per the question if the answer needs to be 13(as stated by op) then the number 5 should not contribute to odd point(3) but it's own point(5), which yields the correct answer as required by OP.

Comment: Thank you @AnuragSrivastava this is very helpful! I knew I was somehow close, thanks for explaining it step by step.

Comment: In this case, it's asking for number 5 not being counted as a regular odd number. So I had to change it slightly to this:

if (my_numbers[i] % 2 === 1 && my_numbers[i] !== 5) {
      total = total + 3
    }

Comment: You're much welcome @EsinYil.